# Make Python open a picture from URL

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I did this project, where you train machine learning to respond to what you say to it.

Here is the Python code I got:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
 
def classify(text):
    key = "#my credits activation key"
    url = "https://machinelearningforkids.co.uk/api/scratch/"+ key + "/classify"
 
    response = requests.get(url, params={ "data" : text })
 
    if response.ok:
        responseData = response.json()
        topMatch = responseData[0]
        return topMatch
    else:
        response.raise_for_status()
 
input = input("What do you want to tell me? > ")
 
recognized = classify(input)
 
label = recognized["class_name"]
 
if label == "kind_things":
    print ("Mmm, thanks")
    img = Image.open("happy.png")
    img.show()
else:
    print ("Well screw you too!")
    img = Image.open("sad.png")
    img.show()
```

This way it works, so I assume I have everything properly installed (pip, Pillow, etc.).

Now, I wanted to take this one step further and make an executable file out of it (with PyInstaller, which I did) and send it to my friends as a joke. The idea is that if they write something nice, they get the nice response and a picture of me smiling is opened from a URL. If they say mean things, then they get the mean response and an angry picture of me opens.

This is what I have tried to far:

```
if label == "kind_things":
    print ("Mmm, thanks")
    url = "#url of the picture"
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(response.raw)
    img.show()
else:
    print ("Well screw you too!")
    url = "#url of the other picture"
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(response.raw)
    img.show()
```

It doesn't work. The error I get in python:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023B5072C180>
```

I read about stuff like `urllib` or `bytesIO` or `StringIO`, but am unsure how to use any of them in this case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you definitely need to open the images from the web? Unless there's a reason you need to, it would probably make more sense to include them in the PyInstaller executable. (And as Ollie pointed out, [swearing is not okay here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites).)

Comment: There is no need to say "please do not laugh at me" we all are here to learn and teach each other:) Keep it up.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message when you run `.exe` in console/terminal/cmd.exe?

Comment: by the way - `im.show()` saves image in temporary file and it uses external program to display it. So you could do the same without using `PIL`

Comment: as I remeber `Image.open` need file name, not raw data - `response.raw` - so you would have to first save `response.raw` in file and later use its name in `Image.open`. For open directly  raw data you would need diffrent methods. Or you would have to use `open` with `io.BytesIO`

Comment: I am sorry for the profanity, I forgot to change it xD
@CrazyChucky The pictures do not need to be from an URL. Can you give me more info on how I can add them to the .exe file or use this im.show()?
I added the error I get. It is in python

Comment: your real problem can be `PyInstaller`, not your code. `Python` wasn't created to build `.exe` files and tools like `PyInstaller` has problem to find all needed Python modules and `C/C++` libraries - and later `.exe` may not work. You may have to manually add needed modules/libraries. See `PyInstaller` doc: [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) and [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). Your .exe may need `C/C++` library to read `.png`

Comment: first you should check what you get in `response` and `response.content` because server may send something different then you expect - ie. `Captcha` to block servers/bots/spamers/hackers. And if you use filename then first try with `/full/path/tp/image.png` because program may run in different folder then you expect and it may try to find image in different folder then you expect. In PyInstaller should be information how to add resource (image/files) to .exe and how to generate full path to these resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the images remotely on the web, this should work:

```py
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from PIL import Image

response = requests.get('http://the/url')
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.show()
```

That said, it probably makes more sense to [include the images along with your executable](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files). You can use the [`--onefile`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=onefile#what-to-generate) option to pack them into the .exe file, rather than have them alongside it in a folder, to obscure the workings a little. (I imagine you'd lose some of the amusing surprise effect if your friends see the images as soon as you give them the program.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried using your code and sadly I get the same error: 
`PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023B5072C180>`

I tried creating a single .exe with the pic inside:

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-data "C:/Users/joodo/Documents/Machine Learning Project/happy.png;." --add-data "C:/Users/joodo/Documents/Machine Learning Project/sad.png;."  "C:/Users/joodo/Documents/Machine Learning Project/makemehappy.py" `

But when I open the file the console just closes and no picture is being shown.

Comment: @IvelinGeorgiev Are you sure the URL is correct, and the file at that location is a valid image? If I replace the dummy URL with that of a real image and run the script, it opens. As for the second part, what's with the `;.` after each file name?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will check everything and try to figure something out in the following days. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by downloading the image. Then showing it with PIL.

To download an image you can use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)`. And later you should delete it by `os.remove`.

Put it all together:

```py
from os import remove
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from PIL import Image
tmp_path = "path to where you want to save it"
urlretrieve("path to your image", tmp_path)
Image.open(tmp_path).show()
remove(tmp_path)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.